# Finding the closest value in an array of floats efficiently

Tags: performance, search, julia

Given a (sorted) array **A** and a reference value **b** I want to find the value **x ∈ A** which has the lowest absolute difference to **b** efficiently.

**A** is quite large (smallest order of magnitude is 10⁶ elements).

My first naive approach was to compute the following (written in Julia):

```
function find_closest(array, element)
    argmin(abs.(array .- element))
end
```

I was wondering you can do better than that. Unfortunately, most of the related questions deal with integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since **A** is sorted, it should be faster to go for

```
function find_closest(A::AbstractArray{T}, b::T) where {T<:Real}
    if length(A) <= 1
        return firstindex(A)
    end

    i = searchsortedfirst(A, b)

    if i == firstindex(A)
        return i
    elseif i > lastindex(A)
        return lastindex(A)
    else
        prev_dist = b - A[i-1]
        next_dist = A[i] - b

        if prev_dist < next_dist
            return i - 1
        else
            return i
        end
    end
end
```

since `searchsorted`-like functions perform in `O(log n)`.

Comment: You can make it a little bit concise by `a<b ? i-1 : i`. And if i==0 then we will have an error. Because array[-1] is meaniness in Julia.

Comment: Would need to add e.g. `i == firstindex(array) && return i` and `i == lastindex(array) + 1 && return lastindex(array)` after the search to handle the boundaries. Can also use `abs2` instead to avoid computing the square root.

Comment: Alternatively, since `array` is sorted, it is possible to compare `element - array[i - 1]` and `array[i] - element` directly (without `abs` or `abs2`, assuming `eltype(array) <: Real`).

Comment: Since you are trying to optimize this, it might be the case you need to find the closest element many times for a batch of numbers. In this case, there might be more optimizations beyond `searchsortedfirst`.

Comment: After some quick benchmarking, the `searchsortedfirst`-function speeds this up by a factor 1000. Thanks so far :)

Comment: @DanGetz What further optimizations do you have in mind?

Comment: `searchsortedfirst` uses binary search. Essentially repeating the same comparisons initially for all searches in the same vector. If a large chunk of searches is done in bulk (i.e. replace a vector with the closest matches in the searched vector), AND if it is still a hot/critical section of code, better search can be done.

Comment: I still can't see how it could be faster unless it is assumed that `b::Vector{T}` is also sorted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean @DanGetz. Can you elaborate a bit more?